# How to access a php class file from PHPFox framework into javascript code written in simple HTML file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events, phpfox

I've a website that is developed using **PHPFox v3.0.7**.

Now I'm trying to implement 'SSE(Server Sent Events)' into one of the PHP files. For your reference I'm giving below only the necessary code part of the file. The file is titled as **process.class.php** and is present at location `/var/www/module/notification/include/service/process.class.php` present on a server having ip `http://34.124.40.142/`.

```
<?php
/**
 * [PHPFOX_HEADER]
 */
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
 * @author          Raymond Benc
 * @package         Phpfox_Service
 * @version         $Id: service.class.php 67 2009-01-20 11:32:45Z Raymond_Benc $
 */
class Notification_Service_Process extends Phpfox_Service 
{
    /**
     * Class constructor
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->_sTable = Phpfox::getT('notification');
    }

    public function add($sType, $iItemId, $iOwnerUserId, $iSenderUserId = null)
    {
        if ($iOwnerUserId == Phpfox::getUserId()&&$iSenderUserId==null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ($sPlugin = Phpfox_Plugin::get('notification.service_process_add'))
        {
            eval($sPlugin);
        }       

        if (isset($bDoNotInsert) || defined('SKIP_NOTIFICATION'))
        {
            return true;
        }

        $aInsert = array(
            'type_id' => $sType,
            'item_id' => $iItemId,
            'user_id' => $iOwnerUserId, 
            'owner_user_id' => ($iSenderUserId === null ? Phpfox::getUserId() : $iSenderUserId),
            'time_stamp' => PHPFOX_TIME     
        );  
        $this->database()->insert($this->_sTable, $aInsert);
        echo "data: The notification is generated". PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        ob_flush();
        flush();


        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

To access this file ant get event data(i.e. the message "The notification is generated") from it I wrote following simple HTML file having source as `process.class.php`:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("http://34.124.40.142/module/notification/include/service/process.class.php");

  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert(event.data);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I run this file in a browser I got following error in a firebug console :
**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://34.124.40.142/module/notification/include/service/process.class.php.**

Now someone please help me by telling how could I make this file accessible in javascript code written in HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: When I got to that URL, I see "NO DICE" in my browser. You are probably missing proper initialization of the framework. Show that script this URL is referring to. And in other news: Are  you seriously using `eval()` in production code? WTF! It's bad for performance, not to mention the possible security implications.

Comment: @Sven: Yes, you are right. I've not initialized the framework. Now in a plain HTML file how should I initialize the framework? The script this URL pointing to is given in the question body itself(process.class.php). You can see "NO DICE", the output you got is present in the file.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to use PHPFox, but I am very sure that you are not supposed to directly access any internal classes. That means you cannot access `module/notification/include/service/process.class.php` directly (assuming that inside this file is your class from above).

Comment: @Sven : I also think the same. Then how should I implement SSE if such is the case? It's very easy to implement in a demo example but in a framework it's too much difficult. Please provide me some solution.

Comment: A solution should be obvious: Use a URL that points to a file that does not cancel execution if the constant PHPFOX is not defined.